# What's wrong with my "textcleaner" script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to fix a `textcleaner` script (into python project) from [Fred's ImageMagick Scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php).

I'm receiving the following error:

```
> File "./textcleaner", line 200
>    {
>    ^
> IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Here is my code:

```
usage1() 
    {
    echo >&2 ""
    echo >&2 "$PROGNAME:" "$@"
    sed >&2 -e '1,/^####/d;  /^###/g;  /^#/!q;  s/^#//;  s/^ //;  4,$p' "$PROGDIR/$PROGNAME"
    }
usage2() 
    {
    echo >&2 ""
    echo >&2 "$PROGNAME:" "$@"
    sed >&2 -e '1,/^####/d;  /^######/g;  /^#/!q;  s/^#*//;  s/^ //;  4,$p' "$PROGDIR/$PROGNAME"
    }
```

Comment: Why the `python-3.x` and `opencv` tags?

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: thanks for your reply , i use it in python project , but i have converted tags to python

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, in all versions of Python, every single line would raise a syntax error.

Comment: `@Youssri Abo Elseod` Please contact me. My textcleaner script requires licensing if using or converting for commercial purposes. See my email address and usage statement in the header of the script. That code is directly from my `bash shell` script. It does not work in Python. You can call the script from Python using its subprocess call

Comment: I can get exactly your error by running your script through python.  Sounds like you are using python instead of bash.

Comment: @fmw42 I did some digging and your work is incredible to say the least, absolutely brilliant.

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for your wonderful work , but my project so far not for commercial use, i am trying to developing some of my work tools , but i will contact you if my project convert based on your script for commercial use at any stage

Comment: thanks @cdarke  for your support i am searching for alternate python script for clean    handwriting text on photo

Comment: thanks @LogicalBranch for clearly me for that i will try another way

Comment: `@Youssri Abo Elseod`. Not to belabor this, but your bio shows you are working at a commercial company. So if you are using the script for work, then it is considered a commercial situation and would require licensing by your company. If this is for personal use, then the way to use it is to use a Python subprocess call to the bash script. If this script is not set up properly according to my home page, then you may get an error message from that part of the script. But it will still process the image successfully. The error is because the script is not in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're getting this error because of how you're indenting your code.

Try using standard indentation instead:

```
usage1() {
  echo >&2 ""
  echo >&2 "$PROGNAME:" "$@"
  sed >&2 -e '1,/^####/d;  /^###/g;  /^#/!q;  s/^#//;  s/^ //;  4,$p' "$PROGDIR/$PROGNAME"
}

usage2() {
  echo >&2 ""
  echo >&2 "$PROGNAME:" "$@"
  sed >&2 -e '1,/^####/d;  /^######/g;  /^#/!q;  s/^#*//;  s/^ //;  4,$p' "$PROGDIR/$PROGNAME"
}
```

Comment: Unix shell script is not sensitive to indenting like Python. The position of the braces is not important. There are several styles of doing that. I use one that suits me and works fine in my shell scripts.

Comment: The error message shown comes from python, not bash (or any other UNIX shell).

Comment: `@cdarke`. Yes, that is correct. But he is trying to use code from Bash directly in a Python script, which will not work.

Comment: thanks @LogicalBranch its worked , i have used Ubuntu for execute this scrip and convert any empty line as your example,

Comment: @YoussriAboElseod You're very welcome, good luck with your project.